how to render webpage in QT app using QWebEngineView?
followed this documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwebenginewidgets-module.html
and written this code
#include <QApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDialogButtonBox>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QWebEngineView>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWebEngineView view;
    view.load(QUrl(QString("https://qt-project.org/")));
    view.resize(1024, 750);
    view.show();  

    return a.exec();
}

no error is coming and page is also not rendering, can anybody help me what i am doing wrong?
Qt version 5.12.12 and OS Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
using CMake to build my project
here is my CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
add_definitions(-fPIC)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/Qt5.12.12/5.12.12/gcc_64")

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Gui Core Widgets WebEngineWidgets 
PrintSupport REQUIRED)
include_directories(
    ./inc
)
add_executable(browser
    src/app_main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(browser
    Qt5::Gui
    Qt5::Widgets 
    Qt5::PrintSupport
    Qt5::WebEngineWidgets
)


As already requested, please provide details about your environment, including Qt and OS versions. Also, be aware that creating alternate accounts is frown upon.

All these files mainwindow.* are required to reproduce the problem? Or just copy-paste from Qt6 docs will do?

just copy paste will do.

@sushantsinghsikarwar Have you tested it with a more recent OS and/or Qt version? 5.12 was released more than 5 years ago, which is a lot of time. For all we know, it could be a bug with that specific version that could make it incompatible with your system, if you did some updates in the meantime (specifically, graphics related).
